# Don't understand why I can not load-balance multiple servers each running the same docker container

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

### Halp

I know that to do this I should be using docker swarm mode or k8s or some other orchestration tool, but I do not understand why what I am trying does not work, can anyone please give me some insight so I can report accurately to my team and motivate for moving to a proper orchestration service? I am hesitant to say "it simply doesn't work" (please see details of what I we were trying to do below) because I will doubtlessly be asked why.

### Details of what we are trying, which doesn't work

Our small team has been learning how to build docker containers for deploy. We run a docker container on a server in AWS with its port 80 mapped to the server's port 80 and some directories mounted in the container. There is an AWS load balancer which adds HTTPS to this HTTP-internal setup. This works really well for single servers behind the LB, however as soon as we have two of these behind the LB both running the same container and try to load-balance them we get 401 errors.

We ensured the setup of each server behind the LB are absolutely identical. We expected this to simply work since it is a really simple, uncomplicated setup. Please be kind, I know it's a very low-level question but I have searched thoroughly and can not find any good advice.

Comment: Without looking at what you are doing, it will be hard to help. But 401 errors are unauthorized errors, how are you managing the session/authentication? In a distributed system i.e. having multiple instances of server running, if one server is generating auth token, then another server must be able to validate. Load balancer may shuffle your incoming request among their target groups.

Comment: You can perfectly run multiple instances of precisely the same docker container without using k8s or swarm. I suggest you look around AWS elastic beanstalk as it's more straightforward to set up, or if you want a bit more advanced, then go for AWS ECS. Beanstalk also offers you autoscaling out of the box and will create load balancers and target groups for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

401 HTTP errors indicate the user is "Unauthorized". When suddenly encountering 401 errors as soon as you add a second server in a load balanced environment, this indicates that your login/authorization system is not designed to operate in a load balanced environment.

What is happening is you are logging into one server, but the load balancer is sending your requests to both servers (request 1 goes to server 1, request 2 goes to server 2, request 3 goes to server 1, etc...) but server 2 doesn't see that you are logged in, because that login state information is over on server 1.

The *easy* way to solve this is to enable [sticky sessions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/sticky-sessions.html) on the load balancer. With this feature enabled, all requests from user 1 will go to server 1, all requests from user 2 will go to server 2, etc...

The *better* way to solve this is to design your system to store logged-in session state in a shared location, such as in your database or a Redis cache or something. Then each server would see that the user is logged in. You would have to provide much more information about your application in your question in order to receive help with that task.